# how to assign variable value in this touch command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, touch, brace-expansion

> first i want to read number of files that he want to create it

```
#!/bin/bash

touch file{0..$number}
```

*I trayed  with this syntax but output is the following*

```
    file{0..number}      >> as example
```

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` variable expansion happens after sequence expression expansion, so you can't use variables inside a sequence expression.

Instead you need to use something like a for loop:

```
number=3
for ((i=0; i<=number; i++))
do
  touch file${i}
done
```